# Deleting specific images from Windows Image Backup

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, windows-8.1

When using the Windows 8.1 Image Backup feature, the system creates several files and folders, in this structure:

- ComputerName

  - Backup 2014-04-02 094800
  - Catalog
  - Logs
  - SPPMetadataCache

My question is this:
What is the proper way to delete only specific backups from this folder?
Can I just delete the `Backup 2014-04-02 094800` folder? Or is it referenced from the Catalog or other meta data?

The only available material I could find refers to Windows 7, which seems to had a specific function for this ("Manage Space").

Thanks for any information.

Comment: If you delete `Backup 2014-04-02 094800` you basically delete the backup image.  Why would you do that?

Comment: I am looking for a safe way to delete old image backups. I wish to create a new image on a regular basis, and remove older ones as time goes by.